# Music stream interrupted by Facebook likes

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, facebook, music-player, oneplus-one

Today my OnePlus One (Android 5.0.1-BlissPop) doesn't work as expected. Usually, I surf on Facebook (using the app, not by browser) and at the same time, I listen to some music with the player Shuttle (regularly available on the Play Store).

This morning, every time I press the "like" button, music stream get interrupted for one second, like the button pressing action override the music stream with another one not well defined.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try and see if there is any sound setting related to Likes in Facebook app? Did you attempt to use an another music player and see whether it suffers the same interruption from the Likes in Facebook app? Did you do a reboot (I don't know why but many folks report success in their problem after doing so)?

Comment: A reboot seems to solve the problem, thanks for the hint :)